# Would like help with Tattoo wording: "forever in my arms"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have tried to translate "Forever in my arms" and came up with "Semper in Armes" would this be correct?

Answer (score 6):

To make your sentence grammatical, you would need to make it *in armis*, not *armes*.

But these might not be the kind of arms you're thinking of. *Arma* are arms in the sense of weapons, like the right to bear arms. It's the ancestor of the English *armament* and *army*.

If you are instead referring to a part of the body, you would use the word *complexus* ("embrace") instead, so:

> **Semper in complexu**

Comment: The Tattoo is a tribute piece for my best friend who passed away a yr ago.I have his paw print and now would like to add a phrase along side it.So arms as in a embrace would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

bear in mind that the latin for arms, as in the human limbs called arms, is *bracchia*, singular *bracchium*. but i agree with cmw that the sense is better captured with ‘embrace.’